# Migrating from 32 bit to 64 Bit → Windows Product Id and Key Issue

Tags: windows-7, memory, performance, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have this system → ​​Product Name: 3574G5Q Machine Serial Number: XXXXXXX → Think Centre Under warranty. I called and then chatted Lenovo Chat support, and asked them that i want to upgrade to Window 7 Home Basic from 32 bit to 64 bit, but the Lenovo gave me the false information that it is not posisble because it is shipped preinstalled. please mark my word false information.
 
But later I contacted Microsoft and they said → The same COA (key) is legally usable for 32 and 64 bit windows as of win 7 and onward. He also said the key comes pre-installed in the mother board.  The Microsft Guy was such a fantastic fellow that they called me and the Lenovo customer care India through conferenece call, and expalined them that do not give false inormation. Lenovo team was unable to provide me the COA (key), and later now they are asking me to visit the nearest center to obtain the Window 7 Home Basic recovery media buy paying a price, wich is above 2600INR(50$USD). Mys system is in warranty, and I have  a leagal License this sounds very tortuous and an attempt to drill my pocket. I should get this recoverable media free of cost.

**MY question** → Cant we some how obtain a Key from the Mother Board?

This question is an extension of a previously asked question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1174786/32-bit-and-ram-issue-can-this-be-upgraded-to-64-bit).
Proof [Here](https://www.screencast.com/t/eRP918mBEI).

Comment: Both are right. The microsoft provided keys are valid for both 32bit and 64 bit installs.   OEM CoA's (CoA==key) often only work for one version.

Comment: Thanks sir, but the Microsoft guy was confident. Do you think I may end up not installing 64 bit even after investing money.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would need this program [RWeverything](http://rweverything.com/).
When you run it, you need to switch to "ACPI table" (Move mouse over buttons in toolbar to spot it), when new window is opened, choose `MSDM` tab. On the bottom in the field `Data` there should be your pre-installed OEM key.

If you can't see `MSDM` tab then OEM key could be probably in the `SLIC` table. It isn't in plain text but it use public key cryptography. 
I'm not sure that process of manipulation with `SLIC` table wouldn't cross terms of legalities so I'm stop here, but if one want to explore it, I'm pretty sure there would be some links regarding this on search engines.

If you didn't reinstall yet current version, you may save your OEM key for future re-installation with help of [ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) - a small utility that doesn't require installation. Saved OEM key can't be used on other machines but it will allow you to give a new live for your computer.

Comment: I followed your step, but I didn't get any MSDM tab, Please see the snapshot → https://www.screencast.com/t/LX6nTXr8 {i Installed the latest win 32 bit version. Is this a version issue?}

Comment: @Champion Then it is means that your computer doesn't have OEM key embedded in ACPI (on motherboard). Usually such computers should have a COA sticker. Check bottom of your computer(sometimes it hidden under the battery)

Comment: sticker is partially damaged. any method to know the key?

Comment: Hurrayyyyyyyy I have found the Key through the Help of this Programme → http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html

Comment: I'm not sure that other methods would be legal

Comment: I dont think so that the above method is illegal, because after all the sticker was there that got damaged. what I am trying to say is that Microsoft didn't has intention to hide key for me.

Comment: Wait, I miss the part that you didn't reinstall yet your current version. I thought that you already reinstall 64 bit and it get stuck asking for the key. This change a lot. You can use in such cases (before re-installation) a small utility [ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html), it is much lighter and didn't install itself to compare to belark

Comment: This programme is usable → http://rweverything.com/ when the Key is stored in Mother Board, but that was not the case in my case. So I used this programme → http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html 
You can also use this programme → http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html

Comment: @Ramhound If you telling that "Windows 7 license, isn't stored in the ACPI Table" then give us your version please. In my experience many major brands keeps W7 license in SLIC  ACPI table as RSA key. Simplest way to prove it on linux is `sudo xxd /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/SLIC >acpi-slic.txt`.

Comment: @Ramhound It isn't true, I restored many computers that has broken COA by extracting OEM key that successfully  used  in re-installation. It works only on the same computer. BTW OEM key usually doesn't match COA sticker

Comment: Alex, are there any cases of failure of Key not working on the same machine from where it is extracted by the methods suggested by you?

Comment: I didn't have any troubles never. The only thing, AFAIK M$ has limited times of OEM activation but if you doing it first time then you would be fine. If you afraid to start process of migration (and this understandable), you can make image of your hard drive with help of `clonezilla` or any other similar programs just in case if something will go wrong you can always restore HDD image back to the previous stage as it was before.